# Can file reading callback function be customized in cURL?

Tags: post, curl, libcurl, multipartform-data

I want to upload a file with cURL. Instead of an existing file on the hard disk, it is in memory(yes, I compose the file at runtime and want to eliminate the temporary file).

IIRC, with cURL, we can customize read callback function when sending ordinary post data. So is there similar mechanism we can use to customize callback function when reading a file, especially when used accompanied with multipart post?

Thanks and Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, curl_formadd's [CURLFORM_STREAM](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html#CURLFORM_STREAM) is your friend:

> Tells libcurl to use the CURLOPT_READFUNCTION callback to get data.
>   The parameter you pass to CURLFORM_STREAM is the pointer passed on to
>   the read callback's fourth argument. If you want the part to look like
>   a file upload one, set the CURLFORM_FILENAME parameter as well. Note
>   that when using CURLFORM_STREAM, CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH must also be
>   set with the total expected length of the part. (Option added in
>   libcurl 7.18.2)